Issue: Laravel admin sdk verifyIdToken
Could not verify the flutter's google signin's user's accessToken in laravel firebase admin sdk
    public static function verifyIdToken(string $idToken): array
    {
        $firebase = Firebase::auth();

        $firebaseClaims = $firebase->verifyIdToken($idToken)->claims()->all();

        if ($firebaseClaims['email'] == null) {
            return [
                "message" => "Invalid User, try another email address",
            ];
        }

        return $firebaseClaims;
    }

When passed IdToken: Response post API call
{
    "message": "The value 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI...' is not a verified ID token:\n- The token was not issued by the given issuers\n- The token is not allowed to be used by this audience\n",
    "exception": "Kreait\\Firebase\\Exception\\Auth\\FailedToVerifyToken",
    "file": "/Users/name/projects/backend/project/vendor/kreait/firebase-php/src/Firebase/Auth.php",
    "line": 402
    }

When passed accessToken: Response post API call
{
  "message": "The value 'ya29.a0AeDClZBN...' is not a verified ID token:\n- The token is invalidThe JWT string must have two dots\n",
    "exception": "Kreait\\Firebase\\Exception\\Auth\\FailedToVerifyToken",
    "file": "/Users/name/projects/backend/socialitclub/vendor/kreait/firebase-php/src/Firebase/Auth.php",
    "line": 402
}

Using google_sign_in flutter sdk to get the user's access token. Which is passed to laravel backend to verify and further upsert user in DB.
sample Flutter code which gives IdToken, accessToken.
  Future<String?> initiateSignInAndGetToken() async {
    // TODO: For testing purpose    
    await _googleSignIn.signOut();

    final googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    final googleAuth = await googleUser?.authentication;
    // Note the accessToken that I pass to backend is not valid, and I have also tried to send IdToken instead

    final token = googleAuth?.accessToken;

    return token;
  }



Verifying an access token will never work, given the method name: verifyIdToken. You say "I have also tried to send IdToken instead", so can you show the code for that too?

Firebase can only verify ID tokens generated by Firebase SDKs (not individual auth providers, such as Google Auth).
So, what you're doing right now will never work, because it was issued by the Google Auth SDK (not the Firebase SDK):
final token = googleAuth?.accessToken;

You can only use a Firebase User ID token that comes from the Firebase SDK instead.  If you're not using Firebase Auth at all, then you won't be able to get a hold of a Firebase Auth user ID token, and the Firebase Auth verification function will be of no use to you at all.
